# How to delete file of certain extension?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that should unzip and install some other application, i get new Zip file with installation image via network and then should unzip it and install. All file except the part that Zip file comes with different name each time because of version change and all my C:\ has a lot of .zip files with different versions. Msi file is not overwritten by Zip i'm using but i'm more than fine with just deleting it prior to unzipping.

I want to delete all .msi and .zip files on C:. 
How can i do that via C#?

thanks...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.msi")
                     .Where(p => p.Extension == ".msi").ToArray();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    try
    {
        file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
        File.Delete(file.FullName);
    }
    catch { }
```

Note that I first try to set attributes to "normal", because `File.Delete()` fails if file is read-only...
Note the use of `GetFiles()`: see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/8he88b63.aspx) for details.

**EDITED:**
If you need to get more than one extension you could use this:

```
public List<FileInfo> GetFiles(string path, params string[] extensions)
{
    List<FileInfo> list = new List<FileInfo>();
    foreach (string ext in extensions)
        list.AddRange(new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*" + ext).Where(p =>
              p.Extension.Equals(ext,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
              .ToArray());
    return list;
}
```

so you can change part of my answer to

```
List<FileInfo> files = GetFiles(@"C:\", ".msi", ".zip");
```

Comment: What does the change in FileAttributes gives me?

Comment: @eugeneK: if file has attribute R (read only) or H (hidden), `File.Delete()` simply does not delete it. Resetting attributes to _normal_ it works.

Comment: @eugeneK: I edited my post to provide an example on how to get more than one extension in a single step

Comment: Will GetFiles get just *.msi files or *.MsI too?

Comment: @eugeneK: `GetFiles()` get both, but takes _file1.msis_ too if it exists ;)

Comment: @Marco so using public List<FileInfo> GetFiles(string path, params string[] extensions)
{
    List<FileInfo> list = new List<FileInfo>();
    foreach (string ext in extensions)
        list.AddRange(new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*" + ext).Where(p =>
              p.Extension.Equals(ext,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
              .ToArray());
    return list;
} , how would I add file formats to it, example .txt,.zip, .mpg

Comment: @dames: use `GetFiles(path, ".txt", ".zip", ".mpg");`

Comment: Im sorry @Marco Im still not seeing what you are saying, you have two instances of "Getfile":1)-public List<FileInfo> GetFiles(string path, params string[] extensions) and 2)-list.AddRange(new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*" + ext).Where(p =>
              p.Extension.Equals(ext,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
              .ToArray()); so in which one would I add GetFiles(path, ".txt", ".zip", ".mpg");

Comment: @dames: I do have only one function (look my edited post); call that function as stated above to get all files with all the extensions you want, then do whatever you please with the list..

Comment: @Marco Ive been trying but not figuring it out, Thanks I will continue trying to make it work

Comment: for me "where" gives an error. Do I need to import anything?

Answer (score 17):

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\myDir", "*.zip").Where(item => item.EndsWith(".zip")))
{
    File.Delete(file);
}
```

you can do it with more pattern by changing the GetFiles Algo

```
public FileInfo[] GetFiles(DirectoryInfo dir, string searchPatterns, params char[] separator)
{
   ArrayList files = new ArrayList();
   string[] patterns = searchPatterns.Split(separator);
   foreach (string pattern in patterns)
   {
      if (pattern.Length != 0)
      {
         files.AddRange(dir.GetFiles(pattern).Where(item => item.EndsWith(pattern));
      }
   }
   return (FileInfo[])files.ToArray(typeof(FileInfo));
}
```

Comment: I have two extensions, can i pass an array of extensions to GetFiles?

Comment: no that is not possible: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/NET_DirectoryInfo.aspx

Comment: I have added a little function for more patterns

Comment: If there is a file with extension _.zipp_ (for example) it will be included and deleted with this code ;)

Comment: thanks for quick answer and for the work you've done... somehow i prefer Marco's solution.

Comment: Your solution still has a problem: if you have `file1.ZIP` this is not considered ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do this :

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\MyDirectory", "*.ext").ToList().ForEach(x => File.Delete(x));
```

Don't forget to include System.IO

Comment: While using `EnumerateFiles()` instead of `GetFiles()` is a good thing, you should throw out the `ToList()`. Otherwise you won`t benefit from the laziness of the enumeration (which leads to the same as if you would use `GetFiles()`. In that case you either have to add our own `ForEach()` extension for `IEnumerable` or you simply switch back to the normal `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".msi") || s.EndsWith(".zip"));

foreach (string file in files)
{
   File.Delete(file);
}
```

Comment: is this not very un-performant? you read out all files and then you restrict to the searched patterns. if you have a folder with 10.000 files and only 10 files belong to the pattern it is not very performant

Comment: if you call two times with one extension you need to check each and every file twise :)

Comment: @masterchris_99: his code is not fair (IMHO), but he checks correct extensions, while your code (as I commented in your answer) not. Look at my answer and open the link I provide to understand that `GetFiles("*.zip")` takes also files .zipp, .zipt, etc...

Comment: @eugeneK: for two reasons. 1) It gets all files and then filter them (there's no reason to get `*.*` if you just need `*.zip`); 2) as any other answer this answer does not check if extension is uppercase or lowercase (or mixed) so you don't get file2.MSI for example. Anyway I preferred this solution among others because he was the only one (other than me) checking for correct extension after using `GetFiles()`. So it's quite good, but should be improved using details I've already written in my edited answer.

Comment: As you can read in my comments, I think your solution is not perfect but quite good, so +1 for you :)

Answer (score 2):

The C# System.IO.Directory object lets you find files (e.g. *.zip) and System.IO.File lets you delete them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Additionally, the .Net 3.5++ file "ZipPackage" might let you do some/all of what you want directly inside the .zip file (without necessarily extracting anything first):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*.pdf").ToList().ForEach(f => File.Delete(f));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can list all file with specific extension
and delete all

```
    var list = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("*.zip");
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(item);
    }
```

Comment: If there is a file with extension _.zipp_ (for example) it will be included and deleted with this code ;)

Comment: Well,  we should use EndWidth like  other said

Comment: No, that's wrong! You get only extensions using case: if you use *.sys you won't get file.SYS!! You should use the method I wrote in my edited answer.

Comment: Yes I said like other said and I meant.Where(item=>item.FullName.EndsWith(...)) ..

Comment: It's not correct: you're not getting all files if they have extensions with different case (upper or lower). If you use _"*.zip"_ you won't get _file1.ZIP_ for example ;)